# LaTeX, footnote

Tags: latex

I am writing a document in which I want to have a footnote with this text:

```
University of xyz
Email: abc@xyz.com
def@hfc.edu
```

I have entered this command:

```
\footnote{University of xyz \\ Email: abc@xyz.com \\ def@hfc.edu}
```

and the result is as follows:

```
   1. University of xyz
Email: abc@xyz.com
def@hfc.edu
```

This does not look nice. I want it to come line under line like this:

```
1. University of xyz
   Email: abc@xyz.com
          def@hfc.edu
```

How can I get this?

Comment: I think the formatting of your examples got a little mangled.

Comment: Try posting your LaTeX-specific question on http://tex.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @Zach:  LaTeX questions are on-topic here if the OP prefers, but it would be nice to know what the difference is between the actual result and the desired result, and that's not showing up at all.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `\parbox` and also `tabular` in a footnote text. This allows such formatting. You're also kindly invited to discuss this with us on https://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the \thanks [command](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/LaTeX_Thanks) and see if that works.

Otherwise, have a read of [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Formatting#Footnotes) documentation. While it doesn't answer your question, it may give you a pointer or two for further research.